# Java File deletion in Linux server is very slow

Tags: java, linux, performance, file, delete-file

From our Java code deployed in Linux, while trying to delete an XML file which is **present** in the same Server machine, it takes more than 90 seconds. The file just contains 1 or 2 lines of text. So size should not be an issue. Also no parallel access is done on the file.
Any idea on why it takes this much amount of time, and how to optimize it? Thanks in advance.

`(new java.io.File(fileName)).delete();"`

Comment: Is this the whole program (of course, surrounded by `main`)? It's possible that only VM startup (it can take some time, especially if your server is handling some requests) or an earlier code causes the slowdown. Insert a `System.out.println` before the delete call, and check it. If the program waits 90 seconds _after_ the text appears, then the call is the problem.

Comment: Hi, No, its a part of a method. We have checked in AppDynamics and found that executing this exact code at this line takes more than 90 secs.

Comment: This is likely not a problem with Java but a problem with too much concurrent file system activity

Comment: @SeanF. File System activity with this particular file? This file I am referring to will never be accessed by any other part of the project. Also this file is unique for each user. So, concurrent access of this file cannot happen from the project.

Comment: Not that file, any file on the same file system.  The problem is not Java, it's the filesystem driver and/or the file system and/or the number of files being accessed read/write.  Java just does the same thing that any other language does, or the same thing as deleting from command line.  It's not Java.